# how to tokenise Apple Holdings and Washington D.C. as one token each?

Tags: nlp

Tried using spacy and nltk to tokenise above two named entities as a token each instead of separate ones. that is to have "Apple Holdings" as a token and "Washington D.C." as another token instead of "Apple" as a token, "Holdings" as a token, "Washington" as a token and "D.C." as a token.

How do I do that for other similar cases?

Pls kindly advise.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition), which is not part of text morphology but a separate NLP task. NER is available on Spacy too (although its accuracy is not the best). Try it via Spacy or another package / service (Azure, AWS, etc).

Comment: thks Amit but how to do it in Azure/ AWS ?

Comment: You need to connect to their API...
But why don't you try Spacy NER first?